# Discrepancy Between Mathematica Result and True Result in Special Cases

Tags: summation

Let's define

```
sum1N[m_] := Sum[Cos[x - 2 n Pi/NN]^m, {n, 1, NN}] // Simplify
```

When m=4, we get

```
(3 NN)/8
```

However, if we compute directly with x=1, NN=4,

```
Cos[1.0 - 2 Pi/4]^4 + Cos[1.0 - 2*2 Pi/4]^4 + Cos[1.0 - 2*3 Pi/4]^4 + Cos[1.0 - 2*4 Pi/4]^4
```

we get result of

```
1.17318
```

which does not agree with

```
In[1]:= (3 NN)/8 /. NN -> 4.0

Out[1]= 1.5
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: `Sum[Cos[x - 2 n Pi/NN]^m, {n, 1, NN}]` and `Sum[Cos[x - 2 n Pi/NN]^m, {n, 1, NN}, 
 Assumptions -> m \[Element] PositiveIntegers]` return the inputs in 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug. For some `NN` it may be true but not for all.

```
Sum[Cos[x - 2 n Pi/NN]^4, {n, 1, NN}] // Simplify
(* (3 NN)/8 *)
```

---

```
Table[{NN, Sum[Cos[x - 2 n Pi/NN]^4, {n, 1, NN}] == 3 NN/8}, {NN, 0, 
   10}] // FullSimplify

(*{
 {{0, True}},
 {{1, 8 Cos[x]^4 == 3}},
 {{2, 8 Cos[x]^4 == 3}},
 {{3, True}},
 {{4, Cos[4 x] == 0}},
 {{5, True}},
 {{6, True}},
 {{7, True}},
 {{8, True}},
 {{9, True}},
 {{10, True}}
}*)
```

As can be seen for `NN` being one of `1,2,4` the identity does not hold.

Comment: Given @halmir's answer with GenerateConditions, I don't think you can assert so definitively that this is a bug with the data we have so far.

Comment: @lericr: See my comment to his answer.

Comment: Results that are generically correct are not regarded as bugs. Hence the implicit advice in the response from @halmir" to use `GenerateConditions->True` when such anomalies arise. Also it is fair to expect results with jump discontinuities when the summation endpoint is also used as a parameter in the summand. Stated differently, if you separate into parameter `nn1` and summation bound `nn2`, then the analytic result for the purely symbolic summation has a point of indeterminacy at `{4,4}`.

Answer (score 6):

An extended comment, not a definitive answer...

Treating this sum as just a mathematical concept rather than WolframLanguage code,

```
Sum[Cos[x - 2 n Pi/NN]^m, {n, 1, NN}]
```

I suspect that there are certain values of NN for which the sum is undeterminable. But there may be a general solution, equivalent to `(3 NN)/8` that works for "almost all" integers. I further suspect that WolframLanguage implementation of `Sum` applies some heuristics to arrive at that general solution. And so, I'm not convinced that we're seeing an actual bug so much as a good faith attempt to produce the "best" answer.

As for the expression being WolframLanguage code, your expectation is simply wrong. Starting with

```
sum1N[m_] := Sum[Cos[x - 2 n Pi/NN]^m, {n, 1, NN}]
```

notice that `x`, `n`, and `NN` are unbound. That is, `sum1N[4]` will be evaluated without substituting any values in for those variables. One might expect that this simply wouldn't evaluate at all, but again, I suspect that `Sum` is implemented with rules that happen to handle this case for most inputs.

So, when you later substitute in values for `x` and `NN` and show that it should be

```
Cos[1.0 - 2 Pi/4]^4 + Cos[1.0 - 2*2 Pi/4]^4 + Cos[1.0 - 2*3 Pi/4]^4 + Cos[1.0 - 2*4 Pi/4]^4
```

that is a completely different calculation. If you had defined it this way,

```
sum1N[m_] := Sum[Cos[1 - 2 n Pi/4]^m, {n, 1, 4}]
```

then you would get exactly what you'd expect. In this definition, `Sum` doesn't need to apply any heuristics, it can just do the four iterations directly.

Furthermore, going back to

```
sum1N[m_] := Sum[Cos[x - 2 n Pi/NN]^m, {n, 1, NN}]
```

you should realize that this is a very strange formulation. `NN` is the max value for the iterator `n`, but it also shows up in the body of the sum where it cannot possibly be bound to anything. `Sum` has the same structure as `Table` so replace `Sum` with `Table` to see what I mean:

```
sum1N[m_] := Table[Cos[x - 2 n Pi/NN]^m, {n, 1, NN}]
```

Now, if you try to evaluate `sum1N[4]`, you'll get an immediate error message and the expression will fail to evaluate. Again, one might reasonably have expected `Sum` to do the same thing, but `Sum` was trying to be "nice" by applying its extensive set of heuristics to give you something rather than nothing. But it's up to you to make sure that you provide meaningful inputs. It's the whole "garbage in, garbage out" thing.

Answer (score 5):

GenerateConditions option could give a hint:

```
sum1N[m_] := 
 Sum[Cos[x - 2  n  Pi/NN]^m, {n, 1, NN}, GenerateConditions -> True] //
   Simplify

sum1N[4]
```

> ConditionalExpression[(3 NN)/8,   NN [Element] Integers && 2/NN
> [NotElement] Integers &&    4/NN [NotElement] Integers && NN >= 1]

Comment: The problem with this definition is that you get `Undefined` for `NN=1,2,4`. But the sum is well defined at such cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this confusion by defining

```
Clear @ sum1N

sum1N[m_, nn_, x_] := 
 Sum[Cos[x - 2 n Pi/nn]^m, {n, 1, nn}] // Simplify
```

Now you can evaluate **symbolically**

```
sum1N[4, 4, x]
```

(3 + Cos[4*x])/2

```
sum1N[m, 4, x]
```

(-Cos[x])^m + Cos[x]^m + (-Sin[x])^m + Sin[x]^m

or **numerically**

```
sum1N[4, 4, 1.]
```

1.17318

or map over several values

```
sum1N[4, 4, #] & /@ {1., 1.5, 2.}
```

{1.17318, 1.98009, 1.42725}

Comment: Instead of `"You can avoid this confusion by defining..."` I would say `"You can avoid this bug by defining"`. Definitely it is not a confusion but a bug.